# which spreadsheet formula I can use for sum a cell

Tags: spreadsheet

How to divide a google spreadsheet (with about 100 sheets) in two (or more) spreadsheets (of about 50 sheets each) in google-apps-script ?
I can only copy sheets one by one on another spreadsheet, then delete the original sheet(s) if copy is a success.
I am trying to figure out the best way to model a spreadsheet (from the database point of view), taking into account :
I can't copy the entire spreadsheet file and delete some sheets in each spreadsheets.